# Calling another function using drupal_get_form

Tags: hooks

How can I call a function using `drupal_get_form` when a submit button is clicked. My situation is that i have a custom module where there is only a submit button. So when that submit button is clicked I want to call a particular function. How can I achieve it through `drupal_get_form`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'myform_form_submit';
```

You can call your function as above. Or

```
function myform_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  //execute your function here
}
```

Comment: `myform_form_submit` will work if your form name is `myform_form`